# CommonsRequestLoggingFilter not logging when extending

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging

The following code does not log when I add in the override methods.
If I comment them out, it does log when I issue a logger.error() in the ControllerAdvice.
Using the following property in application.properties.
logging.level.org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter=TRACE
Using Spring Boot 2.4.5

```
@Bean 
public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter logFilter() {        
     CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter()
     {
         @Override
         protected void beforeRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String message) {
             logger.info(message);
         }

         @Override
         protected void afterRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String message) {
             logger.info(message);
         }

        };

        filter.setIncludeClientInfo(true);
        filter.setIncludeHeaders(true);
        filter.setIncludePayload(true);
        filter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
        filter.setBeforeMessagePrefix("Request started => ");
        filter.setAfterMessagePrefix("Request ended => ");
        
        
        return filter;
    
}
```

Comment: Do you find the solution, I encounter the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The logging level has to be set on the class where your bean `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` is declared

Imagine you declared your bean inside class `RequestLoggingConfiguration`, then you would had to set in your application.properties :

```
logging.level.com.mypackage.myproject.RequestLoggingConfiguration=TRACE
```